# Cypress - triggering POST request opens URL of response

Tags: javascript, post, cypress

I have a test where I want to create a new document. In order to create the document I need to click on a "Save" button. Clicking "Save" triggers a POST request and opens the newly created document in a portlet on the same page.

However, when I do this in Cypress, clicking the save button opens the URL of the POST request in the browser. This page simply displays the response of the POST request.

```
{"response":"248"}
```

How is it possible that clicking the button manually opens the newly created document, while clicking the button in cypress opens a new URL?

This is the cypress code:

```js
cy.visit(url_document_sets)
cy.get('.is_flatten').click({force:true}
cy.get('#TcDocumentFile_valid_from').type(current_date)
cy.get('.k-button').contains('Speichern') //Speichern = Save
```

Which is exactly what I do manually. I go the the URL, click 2 buttons, then click the Save button. Doing this in Cypress though will open the URL of the POST request `https://**********/index.php?r=tc/documentSet/documentSet/saveFile&language=de` in the browser.

Cypress does not throw an error, it just opens the URL.

I know this question is very hard to reproduce, so if there is anything I can provide to make the question clearer, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Cypress doesn't just handle it, could make a guess but it would not help.

To handle it yourself, you could try to stub the call and manually set the document to what is returned.

I'm assuming when you say "opens the newly created document" it replaces the whole browser document and not just a part of the page.

```js
const routeMatcher = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '**/index.php?r=tc/documentSet/documentSet/saveFile&language=de',
  hostname: 'localhost'
}

cy.intercept(routeMatcher, (req) => {
  req.continue((res) => {
    console.log(res.body)      // double-check in console you have "document"
                               // you may have to get it from a property of body
    cy.state('document', res.body)
  })
}).as('newDoc')

cy.visit(url_document_sets)
cy.get('.is_flatten').click({force:true}
cy.get('#TcDocumentFile_valid_from').type(current_date)
cy.get('.k-button').contains('Speichern') //Speichern = Save

cy.wait('@newDoc')
// continue testing
```

If you have difficulty finding the new document property, please add `res` to the question and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have clarified that "opens the newly created document" refers to opens a new portlet, not new page.

Right now I get a "Stubbed = Yes", but there is no console.log of the response.

Comment: I suppose that the portlet opens on the same page is why I get ```Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: newDoc. No request ever occurred.``` at the command "cy.wait(@newDoc)```

Comment: Ok, so `cy.state('document', res.body)` is not the thing to do!

Comment: The timed-out error is just because the routeMatcher config is wrong. But given your further info, I don't think an intercept will help anyway. I looked for some reference to portlet and php to see how it normally behaves, but couldn't find any. Do other portlets test ok?

Comment: All other portlets test ok and I had dozens of tests so far. I will take a look into how opening the portlet works in our system